# Ubuntu 12.04 logger won't write to remote syslog

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, rsyslog

I'm trying to use logger to send events to a remote syslog server. The syslog server is Ubuntu 12.04 running the default rsyslogd. The "client" servers are both Ubuntu 12.04 and SLES11SP1. On SLES11, I can send events to the syslog server successfully. Tcpdump shows them successfully being sent from the SLES client:

```
CEIDMLDAP-LS02:~ # tcpdump udp -n dst portrange 514
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 96 bytes
11:07:58.865116 IP 10.192.0.108.34249 > 10.192.3.104.514: SYSLOG user.notice, length: 59
11:09:07.921309 IP 10.192.0.108.34249 > 10.192.3.104.514: SYSLOG user.notice, length: 77
```

On the Ubuntu syslog server tcpdump also shows them being received and they show up in /var/log/messages there. However, I can't get logger to send anything from the Ubuntu 12.04 clients even though logger on that OS has a special switch for designating the remote server. I've tried many variations of the command line:

```
logger -n <ip> Message
logger -n <ip> -d -P 514 Message
etc
```

None of these efforts are shown by tcpdump as even leaving the client server. They simply never seem to happen at all.

I'm running logger from a sudo su shell. Interestingly when I simply use logger to send a message to the local syslog, it seems to record it as from my account, but when I send remote, it records it as from logger. This may be normal, but I include it for detail.

I'm really hoping that I'm missing something obvious like a dependent package that I haven't installed, but I haven't been able to discover it yet. If not that, does anyone have any ideas how I could get this working?

Answer (score 2):

This bug was fixed in version 2.24.2-1 of logger(1).

A workaround is to specify a socket (which is then ignored):

`logger -n <ip> -d -P 514 -u /tmp/ignored Message`

That worked for me, using `logger from util-linux 2.20.1` on Ubuntu 14.04.

See [link](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=684264) from [hackru's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/531766/246185), especially [message #15](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=684264#15).

Answer (score -1):

Just spent about 40 minutes trying to figure what's wrong with logger on Debian, just like you. Luckily, I've found workaround.

Here it is: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=684264

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.